# getting 24 hours difference in android

Tags: android

I want to call an activity which downloads the data if the data has not been downloaded in last 24 hours.But I have no idea how to do this.Can some one help me out?

Comment: when you want to call the activity ?? do you want to call it from another activity or is it your home activity ?

Comment: i want to calll it from another activity

Answer (score 2):

At first save the Datatime then start a Scheduling background task using Alarm Manager and check the datatime with first save datatime. if datatime different is 24 hours then run the download activity.

[Scheduling background task using Alarm Manager](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What about the modification time of the files you have downloaded?

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#lastModified()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29)

Or you could save the last download time in the SharedPreferences:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

I don't think using the `AlarmManager` is the right way to go, this would force users to download the files or data every 24 hours, even if they are not using your app for a some days or maybe weeks. This can be very annoying, i think you should not use the `AlarmManager` but just check for a download update when users start the app.